# If $A=(0,1) \times (0,1)$ and $B=[0,1]\times[0,1]$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, can $f(A)=B$ if $f$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I found this problem on a list of multivariable calculus exercises, at first I thought that such a function does not exist, then I remembered that the image of an open set under a continuous function is not necessarily open.

Trying to simplify the problem, I decided to try and propose a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f((0,1))=[0,1]$, however I'm still stuck in this simplification, particularly when it comes to proposing a function that simultaneously maps both an $x_{1} \in (0,1)$ and an $x_{2} \in (0,1)$ to an $f(x_{1})=0$ and $f(x_{2})=1$

Comment: What about $f(x,y)=(\sin(2\pi x),\sin(2\pi y))$?

Comment: Or $f(x) = \max(0, \min(1, 3x-1))$ for the one-dimensional question.

Comment: @TitoEliatron Better if you square those components.

Comment: @TitoEliatron I like the idea of $sin(2\pi x )$, however I think that $f(x,y)=(\frac{1}{2} sin(2\pi x) + \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} sin(2\pi y) + \frac{1}{2})$ would be a better fit, because if $f(x)=sin(2\pi x)$ then $f((0,1))=[-1,1]$

Comment: Well, you need to re-scale, yes. Another way: $f(x,y)=(\sin(\pi x/2),\sin(\pi y/2))$.